# how to add background image without hiding the container class in the website

Tags: html, css, background-image

I need to add background image to my site. but when I use

```
background-image:url('path_to_image');
```

but this comes over my container class?? how can i make the image behind the container class?

Comment: please provide ur html & css code either on here or in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net to give us an example, this will help us understand your issue.

Comment: "background-image:url('path_to_image');" you applying this style to container ? to some other element?

Comment: To be quick, append an image element with your background image before your container class and also set its z-index property to a negative value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at my sample :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="background">
    </div>
    <div class="infoContainer">
        <input type="text" /><br/>
        <label>Hi How are you</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
}
.background {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('Images/index.jpg');
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.infoContainer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the body

```
body {
   background-image: url('path_to_image');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body background="image_path">
  If you have a static page
  OR add style to your  body tag
<body style="background-image:url('image_path');">
```